# Poor journey performance with SFMC Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are seeing extremely slow (25,000 records per hour) processing of our Journeys in SFMC Journey Builder. According to Salesforce we should see a speed of a little over 2M records per hour and, so far, they have not been able to identify anything that would cause such poor performance. Has anyone else seen similar performance issues with JB and, if so, have you found a way around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails sent through Journey Builder are flowing through Triggered Send Definitions , which are not meant for high volume sends.

Comment: Ah I see - so for these types of send you'd recommend using automations?

Comment: Yes, with User-Initiated Sends.